# What is a zombie process?

Tags: process, zombie-process

Could you tell me the meaning of a "zombie process" and give an example.

Comment: If you hover over the vote icons you will see one reason for downvoting questions is when it doesn't show any research effort. Questions about zombie process are quite valid here, but you should have done a little searching to see if you could find the existing documentation, then asked a more informed/specific question if you couldn't understand something.

Comment: Tagged `homework`?  Oh, really?

Comment: @alex it's a intro question on my class

Comment: Asking homework questions is discouraged.

Comment: @alex: That's not actually true; they are fine but they have to be done right. This one was not done right, as I noted in my first comment. See [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/578/1925) and [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344/homework-policy-proposal) for where homework policies have been discussed on meta. 1eftHer0: You should read those too along with the FAQ in order to better understand what is considered acceptable and not. Your question actually has issues whether it was homework or not; you should _always_ show your research and attempted solutions.

Comment: asdf if you have anything specific you didn't understand about zombie processes, provide what's your conception was beforehand, and what you had already know about them, to better the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process):

> On Unix and Unix-like computer operating systems, a zombie process or defunct process is a process that has completed execution but still has an entry in the process table. This entry is still needed to allow the process that started the (now zombie) process to read its exit status.
>   [...]
>   When a process ends, all of the memory and resources associated with it are deallocated so they can be used by other processes. However, the process's entry in the process table remains. The parent can read the child's exit status by executing the wait system call, at which stage the zombie is removed.